# Sets contain duplicate values

Tags: apex, batch

Here is what I am doing. When I print the values of last set lssetlll, I see duplicates., I tried having a check to see if items are in the set and not add second time, but that is saying that the variable does not exist. When I print the Hashcode, I see they are unique. Might be because it is from two different loops, so the hashcodes are unique.

I have 3 loops. Each of which at the end is used to create a list of object reference(containing contact and item). For each loop I am adding a map and a set. After the end of 3 loops, I wanted to add all the 3 sets generated from 3 loops to a single list to insert them. The issue is that the combination of Contact, Item from first loop might also exist in 2nd loop. When I insert in the last list from all 3 loops, I end up having some duplicates.

```
     Map<Id, C> cRecords = new Map<Id, C>();

    for (SOME_CRITERIA) {
        A someARecord;
        B someBRecord; // initialize as appropriate.

        String compositeKey = a.Id + b.Id;
        C junction = (cRecords.containsKey(compositeKey) 
            ? cRecords.get(compositeKey) 
            : new C(A__c = a.Id, B__c = b.Id));

        // Update fields on junction as needed.
        cRecords.put(compositeKey, junction);
    set1.add(compositeKey);
    }
    for (SOME_CRITERIA) {
        A1 someARecord;
        B1 someBRecord; // initialize as appropriate.

        String compositeKey1 = a1.Id + b1.Id;
        C1 junction = (cRecords1.containsKey(compositeKey1) 
            ? cRecords.get(compositeKey) 
            : new C(A__c = a1.Id, B__c = b1.Id));

        // Update fields on junction as needed.
        cRecords1.put(compositeKey, junction);
    set2.add(compositeKey);
    }
    for (SOME_CRITERIA) {
        A2 someARecord;
        B2 someBRecord; // initialize as appropriate.

        String compositeKey2 = a2.Id + b2.Id;
        C2 junction = (cRecords2.containsKey(compositeKey2) 
            ? cRecords.get(compositeKey) 
            : new C(A__c = a2.Id, B__c = b2.Id));

        // Update fields on junction as needed.
        cRecords1.put(compositeKey, junction);
    set3.add(compositeKey);
    }

    // Now I am adding all of them into set 

    setfinal.add(set1);
    setfinal.add(set2);
    setfinal.add(set3);

    Here is final that I am trying. The first map might have values which are in 3 rd map. But I wanted to insert only one list towards the end instead of duplicates. How do I achieve that?? Not sure what I should do here. Tried something like this

  /*  for(String Itm : setfinal){
    if(!cRecords1.keyset().contains(setfinal){
    for(Object: map){
    add to final set
    }
    if (!cRecords2.keyset().contains(setfinal){
    }
    if(!cRecords2.keyset().contains(setfinal){

*/
```

**EDIT**: My scenario is similar to [How does my set class have duplicate values?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/65606/how-does-my-set-class-have-duplicate-values?rq=1)

But the issue is that in the insert for the object, I have 2 variables which are lookups. I am unable to use something like Set because each record that I will be inserting had to check if the combination of Contact id and Item Id is unique

Comment: The characters `l` and `1` are very similar, and using names composed of just these characters leads to code which is very hard to read.

Comment: This code still will not compile.

Comment: Also, sets of objects are not a fantastic idea, the objects must be identical for the set to "dedupe" them. If you have different values in there then you will get "dupes". For your code, prefer a `Map<Id, Listings__c>` over the set you're using.

Comment: I did use the map as well. In each for loop when I had Item and the Contact. The combination might exist in second loop(and second map). Not sure how I can combine two loop objects and look for duplicates

Comment: Can you summarize better what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Updated the question with more information

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to follow your code because it's not currently valid or complete, but I think I understand the outline of what you're trying to do:

You want to iterate over two groups of different sObjects (A and B), and create records of a third sObject (C) that has a reference to both A and B. However, you want to create only one C record for each combination of A and B.

This calls not for a `Set<C>` but a `Map<String, C>`, where the keys of the Map are a composite key composed of the related A and C Ids. In very rough outline, it'd look like this:

```
Map<Id, C> cRecords = new Map<Id, C>();

for (SOME_CRITERIA) {
    A someARecord;
    B someBRecord; // initialize as appropriate.

    String compositeKey = a.Id + b.Id;
    C junction = (cRecords.containsKey(compositeKey) 
        ? cRecords.get(compositeKey) 
        : new C(A__c = a.Id, B__c = b.Id));

    // Update fields on junction as needed.
    cRecords.put(compositeKey, junction);
}

// Lastly, insert all the C records

insert cRecords.values();
```

It doesn't matter how much logic you have provided you maintain the identity of the composite key - the combination of the two related record Ids - for each C record you create. You'll always have exactly one C per combination of A and B.

Comment: I tried the same. So basically, the same loop, I have for 3 different lists. Now all the 3 maps, I need to add it into a single map. Here is what I have tried. Editing the same code

Comment: @user64977 The code in my answer is pseudocode. It's intended to illustrate a pattern. Copying and pasting it multiple times into your existing code is not going to produce a viable solution. Instead, you need to take this pattern, or something similar to it, and apply it your problem - which will involve making changes along the way.